# foreach on Json is not working though var_dump is showing the array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I'm trying to run a foreach on the decoded array, as follows:

**Array:**

```
[
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Hod Hash",
                "country": "Israel",
                "countryCode": "",
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_",
                "state": "",
                "street": "Shahaf6\nSec",
                "zip": 41343
            }
        ],
        "birthday": "2006-12-2712: 00: 00+0000",
        "creationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "nir@kfs.fin",
                "localizedLabel": "Lab",
                "originalLabel": "Lab"
            },
            {
                "address": "furt@hdf.cin",
                "localizedLabel": "iCloud",
                "originalLabel": "iCloud"
            }
        ],
        "job": {
            "company": "Layer",
            "jobTitle": ""
        },
        "modificationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "name": {
            "compositeName": "Test Contant",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Contant",
            "middleName": ""
        },
        "notes": "Guy yd he hcgd g\n",
        "phones": [
            {
                "localizedLabel": "home",
                "number": "054-8862488",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Home>!$_"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "iPhone",
                "number": "054-7532635",
                "originalLabel": "iPhone"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "number": "03-4214532",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_"
            }
        ],
        "recordId": "908",
        "source": {
            "sourceID": 0,
            "sourceType": ""
        },
        "websites": [
            "www.layer.com",
            "google.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Hod Hash",
                "country": "Israel",
                "countryCode": "",
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_",
                "state": "",
                "street": "Shahaf6\nSec",
                "zip": 41343
            }
        ],
        "birthday": "2006-12-2712: 00: 00+0000",
        "creationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "nir@kfs.fin",
                "localizedLabel": "Lab",
                "originalLabel": "Lab"
            },
            {
                "address": "furt@hdf.cin",
                "localizedLabel": "iCloud",
                "originalLabel": "iCloud"
            }
        ],
        "job": {
            "company": "Layer",
            "jobTitle": ""
        },
        "modificationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "name": {
            "compositeName": "Test Contant",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Contant",
            "middleName": ""
        },
        "notes": "Guy yd he hcgd g\n",
        "phones": [
            {
                "localizedLabel": "home",
                "number": "054-8862488",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Home>!$_"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "iPhone",
                "number": "054-7532635",
                "originalLabel": "iPhone"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "number": "03-4214532",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_"
            }
        ],
        "recordId": "908",
        "source": {
            "sourceID": 0,
            "sourceType": ""
        },
        "websites": [
            "www.layer.com",
            "google.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Hod Hash",
                "country": "Israel",
                "countryCode": "",
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_",
                "state": "",
                "street": "Shahaf6\nSec",
                "zip": 41343
            }
        ],
        "birthday": "2006-12-2712: 00: 00+0000",
        "creationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "nir@kfs.fin",
                "localizedLabel": "Lab",
                "originalLabel": "Lab"
            },
            {
                "address": "furt@hdf.cin",
                "localizedLabel": "iCloud",
                "originalLabel": "iCloud"
            }
        ],
        "job": {
            "company": "Layer",
            "jobTitle": ""
        },
        "modificationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "name": {
            "compositeName": "Test Contant",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Contant",
            "middleName": ""
        },
        "notes": "Guy yd he hcgd g\n",
        "phones": [
            {
                "localizedLabel": "home",
                "number": "054-8862488",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Home>!$_"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "iPhone",
                "number": "054-7532635",
                "originalLabel": "iPhone"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "number": "03-4214532",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_"
            }
        ],
        "recordId": "908",
        "source": {
            "sourceID": 0,
            "sourceType": ""
        },
        "websites": [
            "www.layer.com",
            "google.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Hod Hash",
                "country": "Israel",
                "countryCode": "",
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_",
                "state": "",
                "street": "Shahaf6\nSec",
                "zip": 41343
            }
        ],
        "birthday": "2006-12-2712: 00: 00+0000",
        "creationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "nir@kfs.fin",
                "localizedLabel": "Lab",
                "originalLabel": "Lab"
            },
            {
                "address": "furt@hdf.cin",
                "localizedLabel": "iCloud",
                "originalLabel": "iCloud"
            }
        ],
        "job": {
            "company": "Layer",
            "jobTitle": ""
        },
        "modificationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "name": {
            "compositeName": "Test Contant",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Contant",
            "middleName": ""
        },
        "notes": "Guy yd he hcgd g\n",
        "phones": [
            {
                "localizedLabel": "home",
                "number": "054-8862488",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Home>!$_"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "iPhone",
                "number": "054-7532635",
                "originalLabel": "iPhone"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "number": "03-4214532",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_"
            }
        ],
        "recordId": "908",
        "source": {
            "sourceID": 0,
            "sourceType": ""
        },
        "websites": [
            "www.layer.com",
            "google.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Hod Hash",
                "country": "Israel",
                "countryCode": "",
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_",
                "state": "",
                "street": "Shahaf6\nSec",
                "zip": 41343
            }
        ],
        "birthday": "2006-12-2712: 00: 00+0000",
        "creationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "nir@kfs.fin",
                "localizedLabel": "Lab",
                "originalLabel": "Lab"
            },
            {
                "address": "furt@hdf.cin",
                "localizedLabel": "iCloud",
                "originalLabel": "iCloud"
            }
        ],
        "job": {
            "company": "Layer",
            "jobTitle": ""
        },
        "modificationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "name": {
            "compositeName": "Test Contant",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Contant",
            "middleName": ""
        },
        "notes": "Guy yd he hcgd g\n",
        "phones": [
            {
                "localizedLabel": "home",
                "number": "054-8862488",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Home>!$_"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "iPhone",
                "number": "054-7532635",
                "originalLabel": "iPhone"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "number": "03-4214532",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_"
            }
        ],
        "recordId": "908",
        "source": {
            "sourceID": 0,
            "sourceType": ""
        },
        "websites": [
            "www.layer.com",
            "google.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "addresses": [
            {
                "city": "Hod Hash",
                "country": "Israel",
                "countryCode": "",
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_",
                "state": "",
                "street": "Shahaf6\nSec",
                "zip": 41343
            }
        ],
        "birthday": "2006-12-2712: 00: 00+0000",
        "creationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "nir@kfs.fin",
                "localizedLabel": "Lab",
                "originalLabel": "Lab"
            },
            {
                "address": "furt@hdf.cin",
                "localizedLabel": "iCloud",
                "originalLabel": "iCloud"
            }
        ],
        "job": {
            "company": "Layer",
            "jobTitle": ""
        },
        "modificationDate": "2016-12-2711: 30: 00+0000",
        "name": {
            "compositeName": "Test Contant",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "Contant",
            "middleName": ""
        },
        "notes": "Guy yd he hcgd g\n",
        "phones": [
            {
                "localizedLabel": "home",
                "number": "054-8862488",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Home>!$_"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "iPhone",
                "number": "054-7532635",
                "originalLabel": "iPhone"
            },
            {
                "localizedLabel": "work",
                "number": "03-4214532",
                "originalLabel": "_$!<Work>!$_"
            }
        ],
        "recordId": "908",
        "source": {
            "sourceID": 0,
            "sourceType": ""
        },
        "websites": [
            "www.layer.com",
            "google.com"
        ]
    }
]
```

the array is in the variable `$inputData`.

then:

```
$decodedContact = json_decode($inputData['contact']); //disregard contact as it's coming from the body as key: contact and value: array`
```

when I run:

```
 foreach ($decodedContact as $contact){
     echo $contact.'<br>';
 }
```

I get:

`Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

when I `var_dump($decodedData);` it all looks great... :\

Comment: Have you tried using var_dump($contact->address); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `contact` is an `stdClass` you can't `echo` it.
You can use `var_dump` on that object (to see it's values) or `echo` the values:

```
var_dump($contact);
```

or

```
echo $contact->birthday;
```

Comment: Shalom Dekel, thanks for the reply. I actually want to return the whole object, so I would get contact and all it's node children.

Comment: The problem is that `echo` can't deal with objects (because - how exactly do you want to display them?) You will need to create a new string that represents all of the object's children/attributes/nodes/etc

Comment: ba li lamut, it was supposed to be print_r. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

after decoding from json `$contact` variable is an object and you can't echo it! because its not a string .

try `var_dump($contact)` to see details.

you can access it's properties like follow :

```
$contact->adresses;
$contact->birthday
. . .
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to echo it all try :

```
print_r($contact);
```